# iOS - UITableView Changing Datasourse

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I was wondering if anyone knows how to solve this problem:

I have a UITableview, where the datasource can continue to grow. The issue is when I add elements to the data source, the table cells get messed up.

Each table cell has a text field where the user can enter data into it, but whenever I add data to the datasource the comments replicate to other cells.

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"ImageTableCell";
ImageTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

Picture *aPicture = (Picture *) [self.imageData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ImageTableCell" owner:self options:NULL];
    cell = (ImageTableCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
}

NSLog(@"comment %@ index %d", aPicture.comment, [indexPath row]);

cell.cellImage.image = aPicture.picture;
cell.commentField.delegate = self;
cell.commentField.text = aPicture.comment;
cell.index = [indexPath row];
cell.tag = [indexPath row];

return cell;
}
```

self.imagedata is a NSMutabaleArray.

EDIT

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [self.imageData count];
}

-(void) reloadImages:(NSNotification *) aNotification {

self.imageData = ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).currentUserData.images;

[self.imageTableView reloadData];
}
```

[a screenshot http://www.mikerizzello.com/pic.png](http://www.mikerizzello.com/pic.png)

Thanks

Comment: How are you adding and how do you refresh the table afterwards?

Comment: i'm just adding an Picture object to the data source, and just letting the method above do the samething for the refresh. I just call [self.tableview reloadData]

Comment: @Mikerizzo Please show the rest of the data source methods

Comment: What happens when you scroll the offending "incorrect" cells off the screen a ways, then scroll them back?

Comment: not very much more, unless im missing sometihng.

Comment: @Mikerizzo Also show where you call  [self.tableview reloadData]

Comment: @JustinAmberson it happens when I add new data, because when I submit the form to the webserver, the incorrect data goes with it.

Comment: Can you post some code on what happens when a user enters text? Your delegate methods for handling text input? Also what happens when a user tries to submit to your webservice? I'm thinking that the wrong index path is getting referenced. It might all tie back with cell reuse.

Comment: @Mikerizzo Is the cell ID correct?

Comment: @JustinAmberson Ya i agree 100% about the cell reuse, because when I add data to the data source I also sort the data so the order gets messed up, so when this happens Picture *aPicture = (Picture *) [self.imageData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]; it finds the wrong object.

Comment: @AbdullahShafique ya it is

Comment: @Mikerizzo Go to your storyboard and select your cell. On the right look for Cell Id. It should be ImageTableCell.

Comment: @AbdullahShafique ya sorry it is. i got confused

Comment: @Mikerizzo Can you show us an image of the problem?

Comment: @AbdullahShafique there you go

Comment: @Mikerizzo What is wrong with it

Comment: By the way you can just take a screen shot with the iPhone simulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

I think you might have a bad MVC pattern. Here's what I would do:

Take your custom cell, ImageViewCell, and make that class your textField delegate. Add a property for your custom Picture object, and set that in cellForRow...

Then, in your textFieldDelegate methods inside the custom cell class, you can change set the contents of your PictureObject there. I have a feeling that you're handling text input in the viewController, and the index of the data object in your array is getting mixed up and you're applying the comment field text to the wrong item in the array.

EDIT

I think it has something to do with cell reuse. The contents of your cell are not getting wiped out upon reusing a cell.

Try this block before you return the cell:

```
if (!aPicture.comment) {
    cell.commentField.text = @"";
} else {
    cell.commentField.text = aPicture.comment;
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example of your solution? also, doing that, I won't be able to control the screen. In me using the view controller as the delegate, it allows me to move the screen up and down when the keyboard comes up.

Comment: dont have an example, but you could listen for the UIKeyboard notifications in your viewController. do you know what I am referring to?

Comment: nope, but do you mean create NSNotifications in the VIew controller and post those notifications when they get invoked in the custom cell?

Comment: No, add your viewController as an observer for the @"UIKeyboardDidShowNotification" and handle your view scrolling logic that way. The keyboard posts the notifications automatically. It posts a corresponding UIKeyboardDidHideNotification on dismissal

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35527/discussion-between-mikerizzo-and-justin-amberson)

Answer (score 0):

Have you try with

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = (ImageTableCell*)[[ImageTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}
```

Anyway you can also set different reuseIdentifier for each of cells but it will be bad idea, I  would like to help you but i think need to run this project.

Please let me know if code above give better solution.